# mdadm large memory consumption

Tags: ubuntu, memory, raid, mdadm

Hi i'm build mdadm RAID 6  (8 WD Red 3 Tb) on ubuntu 13.10x64 server with ext4 fs
When i download torrent on the array, server RAM is filled for maximum cap (8 Gb)
memory is free when i manualy enter

```
sync;echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

it is mdadm -D output

```
/dev/md127:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sun Feb 16 18:47:05 2014
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 17580801024 (16766.36 GiB 18002.74 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2930133504 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
   Raid Devices : 8
  Total Devices : 8
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed Feb 19 14:30:40 2014
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 8
Working Devices : 8
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : corvsrv:2  (local to host corvsrv)
           UUID : d6ca33d3:925c7c82:891c9f07:1f2cb07a
         Events : 121

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       1       8       49        1      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       2       8       65        2      active sync   /dev/sde1
       3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1
       4       8       97        4      active sync   /dev/sdg1
       5       8      113        5      active sync   /dev/sdh1
       6       8      129        6      active sync   /dev/sdi1
       7       8      145        7      active sync   /dev/sdj1
```

**edit 1**

free -m output (and still grow)

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7882       7035        846          0         22       6264
-/+ buffers/cache:        749       7132
Swap:         9636         85       9551
```

Comment: Please show the output of `free -m` when your memory is full. Also read up on caching and why it's good.

Comment: I now about caching. Problem is why it use all RAM. and i need to drop it on disc manualy

Comment: No you don't. Cache is automatically displaced as applications allocate memory.

Comment: you mean if i start heavy-RAM application OS release memory? I'm frustrated because while i have same system with 5-disc RAID RAM always be empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong, your system is simply caching data. Cached data is automatically displaced as applications allocate memory. Also, cache is the best possible use for "idle" memory.

Comment: you mean if i start heavy-RAM application OS release memory? I'm frustrated because while i have same system with 5-disc RAID RAM always be empty

Comment: Indeed, that is how it works. There's no relevant delay in releasing cached memory. Buffers, on the other hand, are data yet to be written to disk. Flushing them takes a lot longer, of course.